# Writing a Compiler in C

Tags: compiler-theory

I am very interested in compilers and how they work so I want to know if there are good sources or books to write a compiler from scratch. As I am a novice C programmer it would be perfect if the guide(s) is for C.

Thank you.

Comment: This is off topic for SO; Though there are plenty of decent resources about building compilers (it's certainly a fun and manageable project to build a simple compiler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Compiler Construction for Digital Computers" 1st Edition by David Gries
is my favorite, and it has good reviews

Answer (score 0):

There's also the book [*Compiler Design in C*](https://holub.com/compiler/) by Allen Holub, which is available electronically.  It's also a bit newer than Gries' book (1990 as opposed to 1971).